# two tables got created in mysql with names blog and blog_seq through spring boot entity annotations

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new in `Spring Boot` and such things, this is the first project I was trying to explore and was following a lecture for project creation, I made an entity class with `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations, when I executed the project, two table in `mysql` db got created namely `blog` and `blog_seq`, I want to understand how this `blog_seq` got created and what is the significance to this table.

`Entity` class:

```
package com.SpringBoot.blog.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "posts", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"titles"})})
public class Posts {
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "titles", nullable = false)
    private String title;
    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false)
    private String description;
    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    public Posts() {
        super();
    }

    public Posts(long id, String title, String description, String content) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }
 
}
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:3306/blog
spring.datasource.userName=root
spring.datasource.password=123456789
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

`mysql` workbench:

[image]

Thanks for the help!!

Tried changing the entity annotations and `application.properties` somewhat, but not working.

Comment: Hello, please check and update the text of your question. You are referring to tables blog and blog_seq but it should be posts and posts_seq. According to screenshot and entity code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It basically happened due to:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
```

`AUTO` strategy uses the database sequence to generate the unique value for your id column. If you log SQL queries then you would be able to see an extra query against that `blog_seq` to select the next unique value.

If that is not what you expect then you can use:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

It will use the database `auto-increment` id column and let the database generate next value for your id column.

It might not matter a lot for your project but do read about the performance implications of these two strategies.

**Edit:**
Found this article which explains these strategies nicely. It will help you.
https://thorben-janssen.com/jpa-generate-primary-keys/

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate needs an unique identifier for each entity. It is the field annotated with `@Id` and corresponding column `id` in the database table `posts`. This field could be provided by the application while creating a new entity (inserting a new row) but it would be hard to maintain. Usually the id will be generated automatically by the database or hibernate. This can be configured with the annotation `@GeneratedValue`.

In you case you have defined `GenerationType.AUTO`. This means that Hibernate can decide what kind of id generation to use. Depending on the database. Mostly it will choose a database sequence. But MySQL doesn't support sequences. That's why Hibernate will create a separate table to mimic a sequence. This is exactly what you can see as `posts_seq` table. It's only column `next_val` holds the current value of the `id` for the table `posts`.

Answer (score 0):

`A sequence is a user-defined schema-bound object that yields a sequence of integers based on a specified specification`

In simple words, it generates numbers in a sequence. [This should give a better idea](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/postgresql-create-sequence/).

In your case, `posts_seq` is the sequence generator associated with the `posts` table. It is used to generate `id` here. The value of `next_value` in `posts_seq` will be used to generate the `id` for the next row inserted to `posts` table. [More info](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/2.2/apidocs/javax/persistence/generatedvalue).